# Hazelcast IMap - How to clear all the elements on loadAll(true)

Tags: hazelcast, hazelcast-imap

My cache will have elements which might not be in sync DB.

For example,
In some use case i used set/putTransient in IMap, so that the element will only be in the cache.

IMap.loadAll(true) doesn't clear those unsynced elements from cache.

Advise please...

update: My reload command

```
@JMXMethod
    public void reload(){
        log.info("Reloading Cache - [{}] ... ", cachename());
            cache().loadAll(true);  
    }
```

Comment: For some reason the data delete in DB and i want to reload all the latest dump from DB, how to achieve this?

Comment: Not sure I actually understand your question? Can you elaborate some more?

Comment: Lets say, EmployeeCache reflects all the element in the Employee Table in the DB. Some other application which has access to the DB deletes the record for the employee A. When i reload() my cache, The employee - A record should not be in the cache.

Answer (score 1):

Just invoke map.clear() and then map.loadAll(true)

Comment: In the time gap between .clear() and loadAll(), if the cache gets request for an element, the cache will return null.

Comment: No, if your loading is set to eager, in this case the get call will trigger the load, so your explicit call to loadAll will be skipped since the loading will be in progress. (or it will trigger the load again if the load takes a couple of millis, but that's rarely the case)

Comment: I do have mapStoreConfig.setInitialLoadMode(InitialLoadMode.EAGER); When i issue reload() after couple of hours the cache got loaded using  @JMXMethod
 public void reload(){
  log.info("Reloading Cache - [{}] ... ", cachename());
   cache().loadAll(true); 
 }

Comment: No. the reload is not doing clean load. Still the elements which is not in DB stays in the cache.

Comment: you are good with clean and loadAll, since the get in-between will not return null when you are in eager loading mode.

Comment: Did you have any chance to evaluate the answer? As said, it's a correct approach if your map is set to eager.